# Does Google Maps Android MapView use different resolution tiles for different screen densities?

Tags: android, android-mapview, resolution, tiles

I am trying to overlay my own custom images on top of a `MapView` in Android.  It is important that my images align correctly with the underlying Google Maps tiles, because it is a map of a university campus whose features must align with Google's underlying tile features.  Are the tiles Google provides for a given geographic rectangle always the same size (in pixels), regardless of display density, or does Google transmit tiles of higher or lower resolution for higher/lower display density devices?

I know in the static maps Javascript API there is a [scale](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#scale_values) parameter that can be parsed to have higher resolution tiles returned.  I am just curious as to whether the Android `MapView` is also capable of returning higher/lower resolution tiles.  In the event `MapView` does return tiles at varying resolutions, is there anyway to programatically find what this resolution is, so I can scale my own overlaid imagery accordingly?

Comment: I doubt if anyone would be able to help you here Bryce because the MapView code is proprietary.

Comment: Nonetheless, I'm hoping there's some documentation, official or unofficial, that describes the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this was never technically answered, I believe it may have been rendered irrelevant by the far more feature complete [v2 version of the Google Maps API for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be easier to use custom tiles with the help of [osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/).